# How to generate random coordinates for a city?

Tags: php, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I want to generate random coordinates (latitude, and longitude) inside a city (for example, London)

If we know that the coordinates of the city London is: `51.509865, -0.118092`

I want to generate random coordinates in this city.

Is the coordinates of London a range or what?

I would like to do that using PHP, but I have no idea about what should I generate between the numbers `51.509865, -0.118092`

Comment: Presumably what you've got there is the centre; you'd have to determine an appropriate range on either side based on your business requirements.